# Images not displaying in a rendered pdf

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm tryin to render a particular html file to pdf and it work.
But the issue is the rendered pdf file does not contain an image which i linked in the html file.
below is the code

**Below is my Views**

```
def get(request):
    template = get_template('success.html')
    
    context = {
        'path': f"{surname}.png"  
    }
    html = template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('success.html', context)

    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Paymentslip%s.pdf"
        content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        download = request.GET.get("download")
        if download:
            content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response

    return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

**utils.py**

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
     template = get_template(template_src)
     html  = template.render(context_dict)
     result = BytesIO()
 
     pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
     if not pdf.err:
         return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
     return None
```

**template file**

```
{% load static %}
{% static "qrs" as baseurl%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Success Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SUCCESS!!!!</h1>
    <div>
    <img src="{{ baseurl }}/{{ path }}" alt="asdjkj"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any solutions will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass {{STATIC_URL}} which is like ‘settings.STATIC_URL’ in your template context and use that to construct your image url.

Edit: if that didn’t work, then add a context variable {{HOST}} which point to your context which is ‘request.META[“HTTP_HOST”]’

Comment: Actually i did that i forgot to share show the template code.

Comment: What is {{base_url}}?

Comment: it's the path to the image in the static files directory, here it is `/static/qrs/Aliyu.png`